# How to Deploy a React Router-Based Application to server?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router-dom

I want to deploy the `react-router-based` application. When I deploy the build of my site it works properly but it cannot do anything when I hit any URL of my site. the main purpose of my is to that how we tell the deployment to use the `react-routes`. the code of `react-router-dom` is

```
<Router>
            {/* here I add some default component that show at every page */}
            <div className="App">
              <Navbar mode={"dark"} />
              <Alert />
              {/* here I add some default component that show at every page */}

              {/* add some components that change as route change. */}
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactUs />} />
                <Route path="/city" element={<AllCities />} />
                <Route path="/city/:cityName" element={<CityProfile />} />
                <Route path="/city/:cityName/:articale" element={<Article />} />
                <Route path="/news" element={<News />} />
                <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
                <Route path="/Login" element={<Login />} />
                <Route path="/Signup" element={<Signup />} />
                <Route path="/User/:username" element={<User />} />
                <Route path="/" element={[< LandingPage />, <TopCites />]} />
                <Route path='/page not found' element={<NotFound />} />
                <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
              </Routes>
              {/* add some components that change as route change. */}
              {/* routes end at here */}
              <Footer />
            </div >
          </Router>
```

Now how do I tell the server to use these routes after deployment? the URL of my site is [the URL of the site](https://yourguide.pk/) its workflow is smooth but when I hit the URL of any page ([page of the site](https://yourguide.pk/city) ) of my site it show the error of `page not found`. kindly tell me how to sort this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to create a `public/_redirects` file with the following rewrite rules:

`_redirects` in

```
/* /index.html  200
```

and then re-deploy your site and check.